# RoR syntax highlighting for Coda 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-highlighting, coda

I am curious how to get highlighting for RoR syntax. For instance the Gemfile is all one color and difficult to read.

Of the themes I did download I modified the .sss files to add syntax highlighting specifically for the Gemfile

```
string {
  color:#3adfb1;
}

string.gemfile {
  color:#fdc53d;
}

string.regex {
  color:#fdc53d;
```

saved, imported into Coda, but got nothing. Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the syntax on a per-file basis by using the gear icon at the bottom of the editor window to select a Syntax Mode. That's great for new files that aren't saved yet or files with weird one-off extensions.

For something more permanent, you can specify a file extension to go with a syntax mode. This is under *Preferences* → *Editor* → *Custom Syntax Modes* (at the bottom). Set the extension of the file, without the period (for example `gem` for ruby gem files) and the syntax mode you want to use for that file type (for example `Ruby`).

Answer (score 1):

I've made some improvements to the bundled Ruby.mode that ships with Coda 2.
You can find it here: https://github.com/zenangst/Coda-2-Modes/

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](http://www.djchoi.com/code/more-syntax-highlighting-for-coda) guide:

```
1. Right click on Coda.app in /Applications and select Show Package Contents
2. Navigate to Contents/Resources/Modes/Ruby.mode/Contents/Resources
3. Open ModeSettings.xml
4. Add the following to the list of extensions.

<extension>ru</extension>
<filename>Gemfile</filename>
<filename>Guardfile</filename>
<filename>Procfile</filename>
```

Or, copy Ruby.mode to ~/Library/Application Support/Coda/Modes and then modify it, to preserve the original.

(For system-wide changes without modifying the application bundle, create the directory /Library/Application Support/Coda/Modes and put .mode directories there.)